# como colocar um foco em um objeto TextBox no Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8-1

Olá, eu sei que é uma dúvida simples. Antes no windows phone 7.5, bastava colocar o código desta forma:

```
textBox.Focus();
```

como faço para usar no windows phone 8.1? Fico no aguardo de uma resposta. De antemão quero agradecer a comunidade.

Comment: Tenta assim textBox.Focus(true);

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou, está dados a seguinte mensagem de erro: Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'value' of 'Control.Focus(FocusState)'

Answer (score 0):

Para colocar o foco em um objeto, utilize a propriedade `Focus`, do seguinte modo:

```
Focus(FocusState);
```

Exemplo:

Em um TextBox chamado `textBox`, para setar o foco utilize:

```
textBox.Focus(FocusState.Pointer);
```